# Django: m2m on a subclassed object

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I am using cartridge and mezzanine in my project for products and categories and I am trying to add a ManyToManyField to my custom model.

```
from cartridge.shop.models import Product, Category

class BaseProduct(Product):
    (...)
    related_categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True, through='CategoryLink')

class CategoryLink(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    product = models.ForeignKey(BaseProduct)
```

For completeness their models are:

Category: https://github.com/stephenmcd/cartridge/blob/master/cartridge/shop/models.py#L341

Product: https://github.com/stephenmcd/cartridge/blob/master/cartridge/shop/models.py#L105

However this gives me the following error when I try to perform a migration:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, brochures, case_studies, conf, contenttypes, core, django_comments, forms, galleries, generic, mezzanine_blocks, pages, quotes, redirects, services, sessions, shop, sites, stevensons_shop, stevensons_user, twitter, utilities
Running migrations:
  Applying stevensons_shop.0057_baseproduct_related_categories...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/mezzanine/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "stevensons_shop_baseproduct"
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to add a m2m on an subclassed object? Do I need to make modifications to the Category model?

Answer (score 0):

You have a model BaseProduct with m2m relation with Category.

The model CategoryLink is the repetition of that m2m relation.
Its the zen of python, you are violating.
"DONT REPEAT YOURSELF".
Remove either that m2m field or the mapping table(CategoryLink).
That should work fine.

I would personally recommend using mapping table rather than m2m field.
Its more agile, in my opinion.

Hope you got what you asked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I thought the "through='CategoryLink'" part of the BaseProduct m2m was supposed to facilitate both? For what its worth I'm trying to follow the guide at  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Sometimes, explicit declarations of foreignkeys in an m2m relation can cause troubles. The motto is to keep it simple, isn't it!!?